# What grep/awk/sed command to use to the output that i want

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have a input file like this:

```
COL1: VALUE1 , XYZ: 2, OWNER: (DSF) , FLG: DIT /-/-/ OX if 0X, proc=0xyyy23, NAME=AUDIT
COL1: VALUE2 , XYZ: 2, OWNER: (DSF) , FLG: DIT /-/-/ OX if 0X, proc=0xyy23, NAME=generic
XYZ:2, COL1: 289 , TREK:MRP, OWNER: (DSF) , FLG: DIT /-/-/ OX if 0X,  NAME=Oil, trial=TREE
```

I want to get the output like this:

```
  COL1: VALUE1 , NAME=AUDIT
  COL1: VALUE2 , NAME=generic
  COL1: 289    , NAME=Oil
```

How can I achieve this using `awk/grep/sed` on command line without using any advanced versions of `awk` like `gawk`, `nawk` etc?

Basically I want to get the value of `COL1` (i.e. text after `:` and `=`) & `NAME` irrespective of where they are in the line.
See that location of NAME column got slightly altered.

This is what I could come up with:

```
awk -F"," '{print $1, $6}' file.txt
COL1: VALUE1   NAME=AUDIT
COL1: VALUE2   NAME=generic
XYZ:2   NAME=Oil
```

Comment: `sed -r 's/.*(COL 1:[^,]+,).*( NAME=[^,]+).*/\1\2/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following(tested and written in GNU `awk`).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=" , "
}
match($0,/COL[0-9]+: [^,]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  match($0,/NAME[^,]*/)
  print val OFS substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  val=""
}
'   Input_file
```

I have clubbed the match(es) of string `COL` and `NAME` in each line so in case any line do not have string `COL` in it, it may not print anything in it.

---

---

In case string `COL` is not found in a line and you still want to print `NAME` string match then try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=" , "
}
match($0,/COL[0-9]+: [^,]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
match($0,/NAME[^,]*/){
  if(val){
    printf "%s%s",val,OFS
  }
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
'    Input_file
```

---

---

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk '                                          ##Starting awk program heer.
BEGIN{                                         ##Starting BEGIN section for awk code here.
  OFS=" , "                                    ##Setting OFS output field separator as space comma space here.
}                                              ##Closing BEGIN section here.
match($0,/COL[0-9]+: [^,]*/){                  ##Using match of awk OOTB function to match a REGEX string COL till comma here.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)                ##If a match is foundthen creating variable val whose value is sub string of matched regex starting to till end value of it.
  match($0,/NAME[^,]*/)                        ##Again using match to match string from NAME to till next comma comes.
  print val OFS substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)      ##Printing value of variable val OFS and substring of current line whose sarting point is RSTART and end point is RLENGTH.
  val=""                                       ##Nullifying variable val here.
}
'  Input_file                                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***Adding reference from `man awk` page:***

```
   RSTART      The index of the first character matched by match(); 0 if no match.  (This implies that character indices start at one.)

   RLENGTH     The length of the string matched by match(); -1 if no match.
```

Comment: works perfect, can you please explain it to me, will appreciate if you do

Comment: @Sach, kindly go through my explanation and let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: @Sach  fyi, this `awk` solution is using `gawk`, which stands for `GNU awk`. `awk` and `gawk` can point to same executable, and in your case, I think you are already using GNU awk since you said it's working. Better to check your version (`awk --version`) and to know the difference, and if you plan to migrate the code to other platform, bear in mind that it does not guarantee that it will work.

Comment: awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: @Sach, BINGO this was tested in same version, should work.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 , can you please provide a good reference on match function . I dont understand what is RSTART & RLENGTH and their uses.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  Can you please explain [^,]* . how exactly does it limit only to the first entry before ','

Comment: @Sach  Then it is `gawk` ;)   You can check [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).

Comment: @Sach, IMHO `man awk` is BEST reference, after that you could go through SO posts too there is lot to learn from this GREAT forums. It is simple, if a match is found then `RSTART` tells its starting indexing point and RLENGTH means that full length of matched index. Also `[^,]*` means match till first comma occures in current line.

Comment: @Tiw . oh does that it mean it may not consistently work in the awk provided in the mobaxterm by default ( i want it work there as well)

Comment: on moba this is the version :awk --version
awk: unknown option -- version
BusyBox v1.22.1 (2015-11-10 11:07:12    ) multi-call binary.

Comment: @Sach, not sure if I get it correctly, `mobaxterm` is kind of a jump box to login to server right? so either you access it from `mobaxterm` or from `putty` logging to same box version should be same, apologies if I missed something here.

Comment: mobaxterm is a software like putty

Comment: @Sach, then if you login to it by putty or moba server's version(which you pinged previously) should be same only, GNU 3.1.7 etc

Comment: @Sach  Try `man awk`, see if there's any information about it. Yeah I already said it's not guaranteed. I'm not familiar with mobaxterm so I don't know whether this `awk` solution will work in it or not.

Comment: @Tiw, IMHO, as mentioned it eariler comments to OP, Moba is also a jump box software to login to server, so it doesn't matter from which software we login to server version should be same which OP has pinged already.

Answer (score 4):

You can try Perl one-liner

```
 perl -lne ' /(COL1:\s*\S+).+(NAME=\w+)/ and print "$1,\t$2" ' input_file
```

with your inputs:

```
$ cat sach.txt
COL1: VALUE1 , XYZ: 2, OWNER: (DSF) , FLG: DIT /-/-/ OX if 0X, proc=0xyyy23, NAME=AUDIT
COL1: VALUE2 , XYZ: 2, OWNER: (DSF) , FLG: DIT /-/-/ OX if 0X, proc=0xyy23, NAME=generic
XYZ:2, COL1: 289 , TREK:MRP, OWNER: (DSF) , FLG: DIT /-/-/ OX if 0X,  NAME=Oil, trial=TREE
$ perl -lne ' /(COL1:\s*\S+).+(NAME=\w+)/ and print "$1,\t$2" ' sach.txt
COL1: VALUE1,   NAME=AUDIT
COL1: VALUE2,   NAME=generic
COL1: 289,      NAME=Oil
$
```

**Explanation:**

```
perl -lne  # use -n for suppressing print default at the end of each line

' /(COL1:\s*\S+).+(NAME=\w+)/  # Match pattern and capture them in capture groups first () will be $1 and second () will be in $2
                               # First ()  matches COL1:\s*\S+ => COL1: followed by zero or more spaces using \s* and \S+ for non-space characters
                               # .+ => match all strings between first () and second ()
                               # Seecond ()  matches NAME followed by a word \w+


and                            # bind on the success of previous condition /..../
print "$1,\t$2"                # print the $1 and $2 captured variables 

' input_file
```

Comment: Ahh... `perl`, always a good choice, and so powerful as well as elegant PRE is :)

Comment: @Tiw.. thank you for the appreciation..yep, Perl is the right tool for regex problems like this..

Comment: @stack0114106 can you please explain it a bit to me.  this is very nice

Answer (score 0):

With grep you can maybe try something like that :

```
while read line; do COL=$(echo $line | grep -o "COL1:.*,"); NAME=$(echo $line | grep -o "NAME=[a-zA-Z]*"); echo $COL $NAME >> new_file.txt; done < your_file.txt
```

The regexp in this example assume that the value after COL1 are always followed by a "," (then it take every characters between the : and ,) so you might have to adapt it to fit your file (same for the regexp used for NAME).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ sed 'H;s/.*NAME=/NAME=/;s/ *,.*//;x;s/^.*COL1/COL1/;s/ *,.*//;G;s/\n/\t, /;' file
COL1: VALUE1    , NAME=AUDIT
COL1: VALUE2    , NAME=generic
COL1: 289       , NAME=Oil
```

Used hold space, and used `\t` for alignment.

Answer (score 0):

by gnu sed

```
$ sed -E 's/^([^,]+,\s*)?(col1:[^,]+).+(,\s*name=\w+).*/\2\3/i' file.txt
```